# I use a:hover and I don't want it to have an effect on the photo

Tags: html, css

This is my problem: 
https://youtu.be/5I9K05FJFBI

I'm just a beginner and my problem is that when I click on the logo so it goes as it should but on the far left of the menu is a square and the reverse logo and I do not want there. I just want the logo to be clickable (href = "index.html") and there is no square on the left. I'm a beginner so please write how to fix it, I did something myself, something from the book and some tutorials on youtube but I can't solve this. Thanks for help.

CSS:

```
a:hover {
            background-color: #e67e22;
            transform:scale(1.2) rotate(5deg);  
 }

.topnav-right {
            float: right;
 }

.topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
            float: left;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
}


.stred {
          position: absolute;
          left: 50%;
          top: 0;
          content: "";
          text-align: center;
        }

.zaoblenie {
            border-radius: 50%;
          }

.zmensit {
          width: 120px;
          height: 120px;  
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="topnav">

<li><a href="#">O nás</a></li>


<li><a href="adminteam.html">Admin Team</a></li>


**<a href="index.html"><img class="zmensit zaoblenie stred"   src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="border-right-style: solid; left:  46.224% !important;border-right-width: 0px;"></a>**  


<div class="topnav-right">
<li><a href="vecicky.html">Vecičky</a></li>
<li><a href="youtuberi.html">Youtuberi</a></li>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is invalid - `li` must be a child of an `ol` or `ul`, but just give that link a class and cancel the hover styles if you do not want them

Comment: I want hover style on menu buttons but no on image and i want image in middle without square in the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a:not(.logo-block):hover {
    background-color: #e67e22;
    transform:scale(1.2) rotate(5deg);  
}
```

The code for removing orange colour from logo.
You need to give "logo-block" class to "a" tag of logo

```
**<a class="logo-block" href="index.html"><img class="zmensit zaoblenie stred"   src="http://hdwallpapersrocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Amazing-boat-in-sea-marvelous-wallpapers.jpg" alt="logo" style="border-right-style: solid; left:  46.224% !important;border-right-width: 0px;"></a>**
```

Thank You

Comment: @Pet0nov please refer this

Comment: This is my actually html code: 
<a class="logo-block stred" href="index.html"><img class="zmensit zaoblenie"   src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="border-right-style: solid; left:  46.224% !important;border-right-width: 0px;"></a> 

When i copy your code over "Thank You" so there is again the left square what the code that I sent is not here (left square) but there is orange color.

Comment: your html code is correct. you just need to update your css code that i have provided above "a:not(.logo-block):hover {
    background-color: #e67e22;
    transform:scale(1.2) rotate(5deg);  
}"
this one

Comment: Thank you so much! There are still 2 things left. I have to somehow put the logo in the middle and Vecičky + youtuberi up.

Comment: you can do it using flex very easily rather than using position and all

Comment: What is flex and where can I find it?

Comment: Flex is css framework
please refer this
I think this is what you need
https://jsfiddle.net/wx2fycan/

You can find tutorial here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your question is very unclear. 
Secondly the HTML format is also not proper according to the coding standards.
But still I can help you.

please find below html updated code

```
<div class="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">O nás</a></li>
        <li><a href="adminteam.html">Admin Team</a></li>
    </ul>
    **<a class="logo-block" href="index.html"><img class="zmensit zaoblenie stred"   src="http://hdwallpapersrocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Amazing-boat-in-sea-marvelous-wallpapers.jpg" alt="logo" style="border-right-style: solid; left:  46.224% !important;border-right-width: 0px;"></a>**  
    <div class="topnav-right">
        <ul>
            <li><a  href="vecicky.html">Vecičky</a></li>
            <li><a  href="youtuberi.html">Youtuberi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, find css updated

```
a:not(.logo-block):hover {
    background-color: #e67e22;
    transform:scale(1.2) rotate(5deg);  
}
```

The css I have applied is for not giving hover effect to the "a" tag having class "logo-block".

Please let me know if you need any furthur help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

For removing the square in the left please add the class "stred" to "a" tag instead of giving it to "img tag".

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help. The left square is no longer there, but the "Thing and Youtuber" in <div class = "topnav-right"> are down and not where they should be and the logo is not in the middle. Please advise me how to remove the hover from the logo. I just want a clean logo without the orange color. Can you help me with this? Well thank you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GukrOz7q3E&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Please check my above answer i have given css code and html code with explanation. how to remove hover effect only from logo.

Comment: I can give you proper html for this three blocks logo in center left and right listing blocks. if you want please let me know

Comment: Yes if you have some html where is the menu on the left, the right part and the logo in the middle so please give.

Comment: And 1 question. How can i remove orange color from logo? I want orange on menu icons but not on logo.